# DBUnit how to set properties to test a database that is run in a Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, dbunit

I am building a Spring Boot application that uses MySQL database. I can run an integration test with DBUnit to test the database, but if I run the same database in a Docker container DBUnit fails with an error:

```
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: Did not find table 'spring_session_attributes' in schema 'null'

    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseTableMetaData.<init>(DatabaseTableMetaData.java:146)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:316)
    at org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute(DeleteAllOperation.java:109)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:183)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:75)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:185)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:269)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunPrepareTestInstanceCallbacks.evaluate(RunPrepareTestInstanceCallbacks.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringFailOnTimeout.evaluate(SpringFailOnTimeout.java:87)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.ProfileValueChecker.evaluate(ProfileValueChecker.java:101)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.runChild(JUnitParamsRunner.java:449)
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.runChild(JUnitParamsRunner.java:393)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.ProfileValueChecker.evaluate(ProfileValueChecker.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringClassRule$TestContextManagerCacheEvictor.evaluate(SpringClassRule.java:242)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

This error is thrown for each table in my schema.
Note that this problem does not appear when I run the database without Docker.

At the same time I can reach the database that is in Docker container through MySQL Workbench and I see that the database is present and all tables exist.
My settings in a test are:

```
@Before
    public void setup() {
       System.setProperty(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_DRIVER_CLASS,
                "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     System.setProperty(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_CONNECTION_URL,
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/portal");
        System.setProperty(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_USERNAME,
                "root");
        System.setProperty(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_PASSWORD,
                "pass");
        System.setProperty(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_SCHEMA,
                "portal");

        ...
    }
```

It seems that the problem should be somewhere in the connection `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/portal`, but I am not sure, because it seems that connection is established, but "conversation" is broken. I have to mention that the project itself works fine with the database being in a Docker container.
I would be grateful if someone could help me or direct a little bit.

Comment: When you are running the database in container, is your application also running in a different container?

Comment: No, my application is running from IDE without Docker container. It is only about database being in a Docker container. What really bothers is that my app connects to the database in both cases (db being in a container and not), but DBUnit works only with the database being without container.

Comment: I tried with https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-dbunit-example/ on a mysql container DB and it works. Please remove System.setProperty(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_SCHEMA, "portal"); and try once

Answer (score 1):

DBUnit does not support mysql-connector-java with version higher than 5.1 from the box!

We run Spring Boot 2.1.3, mysql-connector-java 8.0.15, database-rider 1.5.2 with custom DBUnit's org.dbunit.ext.mysql.IMetadataHandler
(something between DefaultMetaDataHandler and MysqlMetaDataHandler,  methods mixed). MySQL DB in docker. Works fine.